OPFSCache.ts:183 Failed to initialize OFPS cache bucket in Autodesk APS viewer
I am accessing a web page that includes the APS Forge Viewer v. 7.101 from a Windows 11 IIS server. I get the error "OPFSCache.ts:183 Failed to initialize OFPS cache bucket" in the browser console.
The result is that I cannot benefit from OPFS Caching.
Same thing happens if I run the browser on the IIS server itself or if I access the page from another machine. Seems to be related to IIS, since it works fine if the same web page is hosted on a nodejs web server. Any suggestions on IIS settings, MIME types, or other things that causes this?

OPFS cache only works with HTTPS.  It doesn't work if the browser is communicating over HTTP.
Is the IIS server, serving the webpage via HTTP ?  If so, then OPFS will fail.
Reconfig IIS Server, to host an HTTPS endpoint and OPFS will re-activate.

Thanks Michael, is this IIS specific? The same web page  works fine from node.js http-server running http, not https.

Ah ok.  So the problem is IIS server.   The browser doesn’t trust IIS because it’s using a self-signed certificate.  Fix this certificate so the browser trusts IIS and it should resolve things
